# строка из собственной программы

Tags: c++, файлы

Пытаюсь получать строку из `main.cpp`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    ifstream f(argv[0]);
    string s;
    f >> s;
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

какую строку я получаю?

Comment: скорее всего там будет путь к exe для запуска.

Comment: скорее там будет мусор, из-за чтения бинарного исполняемого файла, @pavel путь к exe будет в argv[0]

Comment: путь для запуска будет в argv[0], а в файловом потоке вы получите строку из бинарника

Comment: @goldstar_labs,  вы полностью ответили на мой вопрос

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я так понимаю, ответ на вопрос вы и так знаете, и это все для пополнения базы знаний подобными вопросами, т.к. новички что-то подобное могут спросить?)

Comment: @Sonic Myst, нет, я просто забыл(заклинило), что  читаю из бинарника, вот и запутался,...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в любом случае, вопрос неплохой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А никакую - в том смысле, что если там будет корректный путь к файлу, то это будет путь к **выполняющемуся** файлу.

Проверьте - выведите

```
cout << argv[0];
```

и вы увидите, что будет выведено имя выполняющегося файла (.exe в Windows и подобных операционных системах), а не имя исходного файла (.cpp).

А читать .exe-файл как текстовый... В лучшем случае самое начало прочтете - какое-нибудь `MZ` - под Windows, понятно :)

Comment: Просил бы минусующего показать мою ошибку, чтобы я не писал глупостей в дальнейшем...

Comment: ясно.  А почему MZ?  Кстати, значение  argv[0] не интересует  в вопросе, оно понятно

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А потому что под Windows обычно exe-файл начинается с DOS'овой заглушки - микро-exe, который пишет, что сия программа в DOS не работает. А сами MZ (кстати, ZM тоже разрешено) - сигнатура EXE'шки - говорят, от некоего разработчика Mark Zbikovski. Кстати, как-то во времена DOS начальство стало жаловаться, что секретарша все в игры играет... Ну, я и пропатчил DOS - чтоб exe'шники запускались с моими инициалами :), ну, и нужные программы тоже... Все, больше, что бы ей не приносили - запустить она не могла :)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Кстати, значение `argv[0]` в вопросе **должно бы** интересовать, потому что оно покажет exe, а не cpp...

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста этот комментарий в ответ.  Будет полезней

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Какой именно?... Почему MZ или что argv[0] - это exe, а не cpp?

Comment: Я про  почему MZ(вы классно обьяснили), но и второй тоже можно по моему

Comment: Подумал - нет, MZ - это частность... в Linux будет другой формат. Про cpp добавлю.